# Decoding B64 image in Tensorflow

Tags: java, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm having a terrible time dealing with image en/de-coding in TensorFlow Java. I need to handle the B64 because I have a saved model from Google AutoML vision that expects that input format. Just to be explicit the Maven import is:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>tensorflow-core-platform</artifactId>
  <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and the following minimal example shows the root issue:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.tensorflow.Graph;
import org.tensorflow.Output;
import org.tensorflow.Session;
import org.tensorflow.op.image.DecodeJpeg;
import org.tensorflow.op.image.DecodeJpeg.Options;
import org.tensorflow.types.TString;
import org.tensorflow.types.TUint8;

public class tensorflowLoadMinimal{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
            // Get a public JPG locally for example purposes
        String imgUrl = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/"
                + "uploads/2017/10/file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg";
        String localPath = "/tmp/imgFile.jpg";
        InputStream in = new URL(imgUrl).openStream();
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get(localPath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        
            // Sanity checking the JPG; base64 encode 
        File f = new File(localPath);
        System.out.println("Mime Type of " + f.getName() + " is " +
                new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
        byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(localPath));
        String encodedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(fileBytes);        

            // Make b64 string a tensor; wrap in TF structs 
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        Session s = new Session(graph);
        TString tensor = TString.scalarOf(encodedString);
        Output<TString> tensorAsOut = graph
            .opBuilder("Const", "imgPixels", graph.baseScope())
            .setAttr("dtype", tensor.dataType())
            .setAttr("value", tensor)
            .build()
            .<TString> output(0);
        
            // Try to decode b64 as Jpeg... and fail 
        Options[] opts = new Options[1];
        opts[0] = DecodeJpeg.channels(3L);
        DecodeJpeg dJpg = DecodeJpeg.create(graph.baseScope(), tensorAsOut, opts);
        Output<TUint8> jpgOut = dJpg.image();
        s.run(jpgOut);
        s.close();
    }   
}
```

It confirms I have a JPG file, and then fails to do the decoding, complaining the input format is not an image file, with succinct output:

```
Mime Type of imgFile.jpg is image/jpeg
...
Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.exceptions.TFInvalidArgumentException: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
     [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
    at org.tensorflow.internal.c_api.AbstractTF_Status.throwExceptionIfNotOK(AbstractTF_Status.java:87)
...
    at orc.tensorflowLoadMinimal.main(tensorflowLoadMinimal.java:55)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It reads:

```
Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
```

Which can be fixed either by removing this superfluous part:

```
// Try to decode b64 as Jpeg... and fail 
Options[] opts = new Options[1];
opts[0] = DecodeJpeg.channels(3L);
DecodeJpeg dJpg = DecodeJpeg.create(graph.baseScope(), tensorAsOut, opts);
Output<TUint8> jpgOut = dJpg.image();
s.run(jpgOut);
s.close();
```

... or by passing the expected parameter `JPEG`, likely into `DecodeJpeg.create()` or `opts`.

Comment: (1) The "superfluous" part is needed: the 'DecodeJpeg()' operation(s) are what reside in the execution graph of the saved model. I've just tried to isolate them here. Such commands need to be run inside a session to actually execute. So while removing the 's.run()' line would cause the program to complete without error, it also wouldn't be doing anything

(2) The expected parameter JPEG is being passed to DecodeJpeg.create() in the form of variable 'tensorAsOut' -- which I believe to be the base64 string image, wrapped as a tensor, wrapped as output